# Modal UIViewController appears black after using UIActivityController

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uiactivityviewcontroller

**Read my edit at the bottom**
In my app I have a `UIViewController`which frequently presents a modal `UIViewController`.
This happens without problem

```
-(void)flash
{   
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:SEGUE_IDENTIFIER sender:self];
}
-(void)stopFlash
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil]
}
```

however when the User taps the share button, dismisses the share dialog (just cancel or whatever) and the first modal `UIViewController`should be presented again it just shows a black screen.
But the right modal `UIViewController`is instantiated, I can see it in the `NSLogs`. When tapping share button I use following action:

```
- (IBAction)share:(id)sender
{
    self.shareButton.hidden = YES;
    [self.buttonActivity startAnimating];

    dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_queue_create("background", NULL);
    dispatch_async(queue, ^{
        NSURL *url = APP_URL;
        NSString *message = SHARE_MESSAGE;
        NSArray *activities = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:message, url, nil];
        UIActivityViewController *activity = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activities applicationActivities:nil];
        activity.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeCopyToPasteboard, UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList];
        };
        self.shareController = activity;
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
            [self.buttonActivity stopAnimating];
            self.shareButton.hidden = NO;
            [self presentViewController:self.shareController animated:YES completion:nil];
        });
    });
}
```

**Edit**:
After some more research I found out, that the problem is in an `UIColor` category, but I'm still unable to fix it. I have an Category `random`on UIColor with one method:

```
+(UIColor *)randomColor
{
    CGFloat hue = ( arc4random() % 256 / 256.0 );
    CGFloat saturation = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    CGFloat brightness = ( arc4random() % 128 / 256.0 ) + 0.5;
    UIColor *color = [UIColor colorWithHue:hue saturation:saturation brightness:brightness alpha:1];
    NSLog(@"color: %@", color);
    return color;
}
```

This method normally return just a random color, which is set as background on the `UIView`.
For some reason, in the situation that I first opened ``` UIActivityViewController``randomColor ```just returns nil. In fact the `NSLog`in the method isn't even executed, so the randomColor method isn't even called. Why? That's crazy.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: UIActivityViewController defines a private randomColor method on UIColor, which overrides mine.